# Using Node to import files into Adobe Premiere Pro

Tags: node.js, extendscript, adobe-premiere

I have an electron app that I'd like to use to export files to Adobe Premiere Pro. I've been browsing Adobe's ExtendScript docs, but I'm not seeing anything directly relevant. I've been using the basic script below and it adds the test file to a Project if it's already open, but it won't start a new project.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const videoFilePath = `${process.cwd()}/premiere_test.mov`;

const command = `open -a 'Adobe Premiere Pro 2023' '${videoFilePath}'`;

exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`Error opening Adobe Premiere Pro: ${error}`);
    return;
  }

  console.log('Adobe Premiere Pro opened successfully.');
});
```

Anyone done this type of thing before?